# Styled components class name render twice. why?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I used styled components , I will write the style in js formate like as JS in Css . I will attached the screnshoot my code and my output. Please see the screenshoot . why className render twice?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsFWx.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/78EXj.png

Comment: What do you mean by `className` is rendered twice? I see two classes attached to the one div, but that doesn't mean it's rendered twice. Might just have to do with how styled components apply css to components.

Comment: See my screenshot , why <h3> tag class name will coming 2 className why? check = (this) => https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsFWx.png.